# How to prove the derive the expression for space part of Riemann tensor for homogeneous and isotropic space-time?

Tags: curvature, metric-tensor

It's not a homework!!

For spheric, hyperbolic and flat case
$$
dl^{2} = R^{2}\left(d \psi^{2} + sin^{2}(\psi )(d \theta^{2} + sin^{2}(\theta )d \varphi^{2})\right),
$$

$$
dl^{2} = R^{2}\left(d \psi^{2} + sh^{2}(\psi )(d \theta^{2} + sin^{2}(\theta )d \varphi^{2})\right),
$$

$$
dl^{2} = dx^2 + dy^{2} + dz^{2},
$$
or, in generalized form,
$$
dl^{2} = \frac{dr^{2}}{1 - \kappa \frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}} + r^{2}(d \theta^{2} + sin^{2}(\theta )d \varphi^{2}), \quad \kappa = 1, -1, 0 ,
$$
the space part of Riemann tensor is given by
$$
R_{ijkl} = \frac{\kappa}{R^{2}}\left( g_{ik}g_{jl} - g_{il}g_{jk}\right).
$$
How to prove it by using an expression for $R_{ijkl}$ via 
$$
R_{iklm} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \partial_{k}\partial_{l}g_{im} + \partial_{i}\partial_{m}g_{kl} - \partial_{k}\partial_{m}g_{il} - \partial_{i}\partial_{l}g_{km}\right) + g_{np}(\Gamma^{n}_{kl}\Gamma^{p}_{im} - \Gamma^{n}_{km}\Gamma^{p}_{il})?
$$
I tried to do it with hyperbolic metric, but I failed.

Comment: Hi PhysiXxx. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems. Whether it is _actual_ homework is irrelevant.

Comment: Also please do not post the [same question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62384/2451) in a new entry. Re-edit the old entry instead.